# Jade templating from SemanticUI

Tags: node.js, pug, semantic-ui

I have this HTML from SemanticUI which shows the text to the right hand side of a User icon:

```
<h1 class="ui header">
  <i class="user icon"></i>
  Create Your Account
</h1>
```

and I am trying to re-produce this using Jade:

```
h1.ui.header
  i.user.icon
  Create Your Account
```

however, this doesn't work properly because I think Jade needs an html tag of some sort to function and the "Create Your Account" line doesn't have one.

Therefore I tried this too:

```
h1.ui.header
  i.user.icon
  span Create Your Account //also with div and p but these are display:block so no luck
```

but the "Create Your Account" text appears below the user icon and I need it to appear at the right hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other to put text after a tag with jade templating, you need to use the pipe symbol :

```
 h1.ui.header
    i.user.icon
    | Create Your Account
```

Will generate :

```
<h1 class="ui header"><i class="user icon"></i>Create Your Account</h1>
```

You can try it on the [jade demo page](http://jade-lang.com/demo/).

Hope this helps.